# FBSDKs installed via Pods - No such module on Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I installed the following pods to my Swift project:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1.4'
  pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.5'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit',  '4.3.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.3.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.3.0'
  pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~>1.7.5'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
```

I added a Bridging Header for all the pods except the 3 FBSDKs. On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started , it says...

"Swift

v4.1 of the SDK supports modules natively so no bridging headers are required. Simply import the appropriate kit module in your .swift files"

Problem is when I try to import those 3 frameworks to AppDelegate, I get the error message "No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'"

Anyone encounter this issue before?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `use_frameworks!` to the top of your podfile. It solved my problem. Initialy it is shown as `#use_frameworks!` in podfile . Remove the `#` infront of `use_frameworks!`. This [blog](http://iosdevbits.blogspot.in/2014/12/finally-cocoapods-with-swift.html) explains about it.